# How to make cross domain ajax call from visual force page

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, visualforce

I want to make a ajax call from script in visualforce page.

example:-

```
$.ajax({

  type : ( typeof method === 'undefined' || method == null) ? 'GET' : method,

  async : ( typeof IsSync === 'undefined' || IsSync == null) ? false : IsSync,

url : url,

data : payload,

headers : {

                'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Authorization' : 'OAuth ' + access_token,

            },
  success : function(response) {

                console.log('inside success ');
                callback(response);

            },
failure : function(response) {

                        console.log('inside failure ');
            }
        });
```

But this request ends with cross-domain error.
But when i tried to use ajax toolkit of force.com like:-

```
sforce.connection.remoteFunction({

            type : ( typeof method === 'undefined' || method == null) ? 'GET' : method,
            async : ( typeof IsSync === 'undefined' || IsSync == null) ? false : IsSync,
            url : url,
            data : payload,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Authorization' : 'OAuth ' + access_token,

            },
            onSuccess : function(response) {
                console.log('inside success ');
                callback(response);

            },
            onFailure : function(response) {
                console.log('inside failure ');
            }
        });
```

but this ends with 401 Unauthorized error.I can't find out whats the problem here.Please help for this...